# Stuck on Yellow Brick Road #23 in room 4

Tags: aqueduct

Anyone have a solution for this puzzle.  I've been stuck on it for days and it's driving me crazy!

Comment: Room 5, #24 is called "Transport" in my game. I can't find one called "Yellow Brick Road" either...

Answer (score 1):

Had another look and found the Yellow Brick Road level - it's Room 4, #23. I'm sure you've long since solved the level, but a [solution is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHGQQ.png) if not.